# php-excel-reader How can I get a position of TextBox

Tags: php, textbox, import-from-excel, phpexcelreader

Is there any way to get a position of TextBox of xls file via php-excel-reader? I need to get a text of that TextBox [example image](http://creativedevelopment.cz/example.png)
so for example I need "2a" but box "2a" is empty but there is a TextBox on it. So how can I get this value if I know what box I need? Thanks for everyone who can help me and sorry for my English

Comment: Do you mean a textbox (form element), or cell 2A? If the former, I'm not aware of any Excel libraries for PHP that support form elements beside [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php), [PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05) or [Ilia's extension](https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel)

Comment: I mean I need to get an floating TextBox(drawing element) which is floating on 2A

Comment: In that case, you're limited to the libraries that I listed